# count occurrence of value over a range in Pandas

Tags: pandas, countif

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
simple = pd.DataFrame([
    (80,100 ),
    (100,90 ),
    (80, 90 ),
], columns=['content_x', 'content_y'])

    content_x   content_y
0   80          100
1   100         90
2   80          90
```

I'd want to count the occurrences of values in content_x over the content_y column.  (In Excel, I use a countif)

The final output would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try via `isin()`:

```
simple['count of X in Y']=simple['content_y'].isin(simple['content_x']).astype(int)
#OR(via view())
simple['count of X in Y']=simple['content_y'].isin(simple['content_x']).view('i1')
```

output of `simple`:

```
  content_x     content_y   count of X in Y
0   80          100             1
1   100         90              0
2   80          90              0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here's one way ->

Just do the `value_count()` and `map` the result:

```
simple['count'] = simple.content_x.map(simple.content_y.value_counts()).fillna(0, downcast= 'infer')
```

OUTPUT FOR YOUR SAMPLE INPUT:

```
   content_x  content_y  count
0         80        100      0
1        100         90      1
2         80         90      0
```

Another sample INPUT:

```
   content_x  content_y
0         80        100
1        100         90
2         80        100
```

OUTPUT:

```
   content_x  content_y  count
0         80        100      0
1        100         90      2
2         80        100      0
```

Comment: ohh gotcha...so let me remove my above comment

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Anurag's answer, but I think you are looking for grand total per number per row? You use `groupby` and `transform` to get that:

```
import pandas as pd
simple = pd.DataFrame([
    (80,100 ),
    (100,90 ),
    (80, 90 ),
], columns=['content_x', 'content_y'])
simple['count'] = simple['content_y'].isin(simple['content_x'])
simple['count'] = simple.groupby('content_y')['count'].transform('sum')
simple
Out[1]: 
   content_x  content_y  count
0         80        100      1
1        100         90      0
2         80         90      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets use

`np.in1d` to intersect the column arrays

```
simple['count of X in Y']=np.in1d(simple['content_y'].values,simple['content_x'].values).astype(int)



     content_x  content_y  count of X in Y
0         80        100                1
1        100         90                0
2         80         90                0
```

Answer (score 1):

For each row in content_x sum all the occurrences in content_y. This is easy to do, because you can just sum a boolean filter. Then just add that to a list, and make it all a new dataframe column after the loop. I'm sure there are other methods, but this one is fairly straight forward.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x' : [80, 100, 80],
    'y' : [100, 90, 90],
})

x_in_y = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    x_in_y.append( sum(df.y == df.x[i]) )

df['x_in_y'] = x_in_y
```

[image]